# Double ternary. A better option?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, strtotime

Would there be a better way to validate a posted variable exists and validate strtotime works than the following example?

`$start = (!empty($_POST['start'])) ? (strtotime($_POST['start'])) ? strtotime($_POST['start']) : time() : time();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start = (!empty($_POST['start']) && strtotime($_POST['start'])) ? strtotime($_POST['start']) : time();
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes.  Thanks

Comment: Hehe, sometimes it's just more obvious than you would expect ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd check it like `$start = intval(strtotime($_POST['start']) > 0 ? intval(strtotime($_POST['start']) : time();`

Answer (score -1):

```
$startIsEmpty = empty($_POST['start']);
$startIsConvertible = strtotime($_POST['start']);
$start = !$startIsEmpty && $startIsConvertible ? strtotime($_POST['start']) : time();
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: what is your issue with the answer?